# Unable to create a site column based on the Managed metadata type?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata

We are facing an issue while trying to create a site/List column based on the Managed metadata type on a specific Site collection on our SharePoint 2010 farm, it throws the below mentioned access denied error eventhough the user has Full control on the site collection:

Access Denied. Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))  
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd)   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd).

However, we are able to do it on the other site collection on the same webapplication. any help?

Also, would it be possible to define a termset on the site collection level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was resolve by granting permissions to users in the hidden Taxonomy list, which can be browsed by putting this on the end of your Site Collection URL Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/

Answer (score 3):

This one is a bit weird to fix but it is fixable.

1) Open up your central admin and go to "/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx"

2) Locate the Managed Metadata service, and click on the white space next to the link

3) Click "Permissions" on the toolbar

4) Select the "Farm" user from the middle box, if it is not present at all then add   "Sharepoint Farm" (Or whatever your farm user account is) at the top.

5) Select ONLY the one permission for "Read Access To Term Store"

The actual reason as to why this happens to me appears to be around the changing of a service account name. Not sure why removing permissions usually fixes this but it does and I haven't been able to find out the exact reason why.

Just a note about managed metadata: You can create termsets at Farm or Site Collection level. Termsets created from site actions in the site collection are scoped to the Site Collection, termsets created in Central Admin are scoped at Farm level.

Also just make sure the feature is activated on that site collection, a simple issue there to look, but also a common one, features can sometimes not install correctly, and you can just activate them to put them back.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this with a user with Site collection Administrator rights? The error clearly says Access Denied. So first we need to check if at all this is an issue with permission of the user or with this site.

Cheers

Comment: It solves..But this is expected to add the user into the Site collection Administrator group?

Comment: Karthikeyan, By default if you have full read/write access to the site, you will access to the taxonomyhidden list. I mean site collection admin will obviously have access to it. So it is more related to your the user permission! Cheers

Comment: Contribute access should be OK.