# Group by managed metadata column returns null for contribute users

Tags: 2013, document-library, term-store, term-set

I created a term set called **Organization** and added a few terms. I then added a column called **Organization** to a library and set the column to use a managed term set. I chose the **Organization term set** and kept Allow multiple values to false. I then **Grouped the default view by this column**.

I was able to **add multiple documents** to the library, select the organization from the term store and it **grouped as expected**, awesome. I was also able to add new terms from the library.

Another user viewed this library and instead of seeing the documents grouped by organization as I see it when logged in, it shows "**Organization: null**" instead of "**Organization: *myorg***". The user is able to add documents, set the term in the column and even add new terms.

Here's another post showing the exact steps I used. Again, works fine for me, but not for any other users. - [Group by managed metadata column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/group-by-managed-metadata-column)

Comment: Only Site Collection Admins are able to see the groupings as expected, but users with Full Control on the site cannot see the groupings displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution here - [Unable to create a site column based on the Managed metadata type?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46147/unable-to-create-a-site-column-based-on-the-managed-metadata-type)

> My issue was resolve by granting permissions to users in the hidden
>   Taxonomy list, which can be browsed by putting this on the end of your
>   Site Collection URL Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/

I added all users with **Read Permissions** and now it works as expected for all users.